# Adding 2012 R2 Server to existing Essentials 2012 R2 Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, replication, essentials-2012-r2

I've been running a Server Essentials 2012 R2 single server for 2 years, it's been reliable so far.  Our business is beginning to outgrow, and I have recently added a second production server running Server 2012 R2, (eval version)

My first thought was to set the second server up as a second domain controller with AD integrated DNS for availability.  Reading through MS literature it seems as though this doesn't violate the Essentials requirements as this isn't a Read-Only controller.  DNS will only resolve on the Essentials server though, I get nothing from the second server.

I added AD DS, promoted the second server to a DC, added AD integrated DNS. I can resolve DNS from both servers on the new server, but the Essentials server will only see itself.

The forums all indicate this is possible, so what am I missing?

Comment: `DNS will only resolve on the Essentials server though` - What does that mean exactly? What are you doing and what is the result? `I can resolve DNS from both servers on the new server, but the Essentials server will only see itself.` - What does that mean exactly? What are you doing and what is the result? Giving us those details will help. As it stands, it's not really clear to me what you mean by those two statements.

Comment: Server1 - running WSE2012 R2
Server2 - running Server 2012 R2

Run on client PC's which are AD joined
nslookup test-pc Server1
- gives proper IP from essentials server which is setup as preferred DNS server on client

nslookup test-pc Server2
- I get DNS timeouts

AD Users and Computers show both servers as domain controllers with GC checked.